# Magento2 Best practice to edit layout xml file

Tags: magento2, layout, overriding

Suppose that I want to edit the file

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

**Do I edit the file directly?**

It seems not a best practice to me.

Or is there anyway I can extend the file to override the content.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Is your intention to build a custom module which will contain your override or is this part of a theme you are building?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to override the layout file.  For Example,
`vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<vendor_theme_dir>
|__/<vendor_theme>
  |__/Magento_Theme
    |__/view
      |__/frontend
         |__/layout
            |__/default.xml
```

So you just need to override a file under your theme folder.

Comment: what is theme_dir and vendor_theme in this case

Comment: If you see in app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma - This one is default theme where as if you have any theme installed at that time path will be app/design/frontend/<theme_dir>/<vendor_theme>

Comment: I have only `app/design/frontend/Magento` and there is no additional folder or file inside it. So i add `Luma/Magento_Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` inside it am i right?

Comment: Yes. Please add same as defined

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following things. Create new theme and override this layout in theme. Check luma theme, how to override any xml. And do the same. Check [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html)

Answer (score 0):

To add an overriding theme file (to override a parent theme layout):

```
<theme_dir>
  |__/<Namespace_Module>
    |__/layout
      |__/override
         |__/theme
            |__/<Parent_Vendor>
               |__/<parent_theme>
                  |--<layout1>.xml
                  |--<layout2>.xml
```

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Comment: what is theme_dir, namespace_module, parent_vendor and parent_theme in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must create a local theme, for do that you have to create the blow structure

```
app
---->desing
-------->frontend
------------>Vendor
---------------->default
```

In this folder you create 2 files

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Vendor/default',
    __DIR__
);
```

theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Vendor Theme</title>
</theme>
```

And finaly you have to create a below structure

```
Magento_Theme
---->layout
-------->default.xml
```